# How can I make a session of a certain result?

Tags: php, session

I am stuck. I want to make a session of the ID that belongs to a certain link. However, the code results into multiple ID's. And multiple links with different ID's coming from one code.

This is what I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `lijsten` ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo   "<a href='lijst.php'> Naam:   " . $row["naamlijst"]. " - taal: " . $row["taal"]. "</a> <br>";
}

} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?
```

The  statement gives links for all the results of the rows naamlijst and taal. But I only want to make a session of ID of the link that I click.

This is my first question on Stackoverflow. I hope someone can help me! :)
[Picture of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiABZ.png)
Here is the webpage, I want to store the ID of the link that I click into sessions

Comment: What you mean by "session of ID"

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "make a session"? Do you mean `href="lijst.php?id=$row["id"]"`, give or take a few quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the clicked link ID is not available in this page. It will be available in `lijst.php`, but only if you use something like @CodeCaster example code.

Comment: I mean that I want to store the ID of the link that I click when I go to lijst.php I don't really know how to explain it